# Seleccionar solo un checkbox de una fila por tabla html javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema espero que me puedan ayudar, resulta que tengo una tabla que genero mediante un `foreach` en `php` el cual me trae información de facturas cargadas, lo que requiero es hacer que mediante `checkbox` pueda indicarle si la quiero autorizar o rechazar, el problema es que solo requiero que se quede marcada una opción para cada fila de la tabla, ya se que eso se puede realizar con un `radio button`, pero no lo hago así ya que si el usuario no marca ninguna de las casillas el estatus de la factura no debe verse afectado y con el radio `button` siempre se queda marcada una de las dos opciones.

el codigo de mi `html` es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/autorizafacturas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/gota.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Autoriza Facturas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="encabezado">
            <div class="logoc">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/mex.png" alt="Logo Chemtreat">
                </a>
            </div>    
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Autorizacion de Facturas</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="cerrar">
                <a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesion </a>
            </div>
            <div class="rmenu">
                <a href="menu.php">Regresar al Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <form class="fechas" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" name="fechas" id="fechas">
                <label for="date">Fecha Inicial:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" class="tcal" id="fechaini" value="" />
                <label for="date2">Fecha Final:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date2" class="tcal" id="fechafin" value="" />
                <label for="proveedor">Proveedor:</label>
                <input type="text" name="proveedor" id="proveedor">
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="fechas" id="fechasb">
            </form>
            <?php if(!empty($errores)):?>
                <div class="descarga-error">
                    <?php echo $errores; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if(!empty($consulta)):?>
                <table>
                <form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" id="facturas">
                    <tr class="Desc">
                        <th>Acuse</th>
                        <th>Proveedor</th>
                        <th>Archivo</th>
                        <th>Orden</th>
                        <th>Serie</th>
                        <th>Folio</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Ver Factura</th>
                        <th>Ver Comprobante Entrega</th>
                        <th>Autorizar</th>
                        <th>Rechazar</th>
                    </tr>  
                    <?php foreach($resultado as $fila): ?>
                        <div class="formgroup<?php echo $i?>">
                        <tr class='datos'>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_acu'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['usu_nom'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_nom'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_oc'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_ser'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_fol'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_fec_add'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <td><a target="_blank" href="localhost/almacen/ingresos/<?php echo  $fila['cfi_nom']?>.pdf"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td><a target="_blank" href="localhost/almacen/ingresos/<?php echo  $fila['cfi_nom'].'-OE'?>.pdf"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td><input onclick="uncheck()" type="checkbox" id="autorizar" name="autorizar[]" value="<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>"></td>
                            <td><input onclick="uncheck()" type="checkbox" id="rechazar" name="rechazar[]" value="<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
                <input class="eliminar" type="submit" value="Autorizar Facturas" name="autorizacion" id="autorizacion">
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!empty($autoriza)):?>
                <div class="success">
                    <?php echo $autoriza; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?> 
    </section>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >$(document).ready(function(){var items = <?= json_encode($array)?>;$("#proveedor").autocomplete({source: items});});</script>
<script src="js/revision.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function uncheck(){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('autorizar');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('rechazar');

   checkbox1.onclick = function(){ 
   if(checkbox1.checked != false){ 
   checkbox2.checked =null; }
    } 
   checkbox2.onclick = function(){ 
   if(checkbox2.checked != false){ 
   checkbox1.checked=null;
    }
    } 
   }
```

Comment: Si entendi bien quieres que solo de una misma fila se seleccione autorizar o rechazar?? es eso?

Comment: Hola Dariel, exacto eso es lo que necesito estoy intentando hacerlo con javascript pero no encuentro como, solo puedo hacerlo para la primer fila para las siguientes no puedo.

Comment: pk le pasas esto al value de los dos checkbox `value="<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>"` ???

Comment: Es el Id del documento que voy a autorizar o rechazar

Comment: Estaría bien que también agregaras tu código Javascript.

Comment: Hola Arreguin claro perdon ya lo agregue es una funcion que igual encontre por aca, pero repito solo puedo hacer que funcione para la primer fila de la tabla y necesito que funcione para todas.

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos actualizando, ya logre resolverlo, mi problema era que estaba colocando el mismo id a todos los input tipo check box lo que hice fue colocarles un id diferente a cada uno apoyandome con el id de la factura y pasarle a la funcion uncheked() dos argumentos que son los id de los checkbox que quiero seleccionar.

```html
<?php foreach($resultado as $fila): ?>
                        <tr class='datos'>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_acu'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['usu_nom'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_nom'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_oc'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_ser'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_fol'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <?php echo '<td>' . $fila['cfi_fec_add'] . '</td>'; ?>
                            <td><a target="_blank" href="http://proveedores-chemtreat.com.mx/chemtreat/almacen/ingresos/<?php echo  $fila['cfi_nom']?>.pdf"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td><a target="_blank" href="http://proveedores-chemtreat.com.mx/chemtreat/almacen/ingresos/<?php echo  $fila['cfi_nom'].'-OE'?>.pdf"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar'+'<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>','rechazar'+'<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>')" type="checkbox" id="autorizar<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>" name="autorizar[]" value="<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>"></td>
                            <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar'+'<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>','rechazar'+'<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>')" type="checkbox" id="rechazar<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>" name="rechazar[]" value="<?php echo $fila['cfi_acu']?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
```

```
function uncheck(autorizar, rechazar){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById(autorizar);
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById(rechazar);
   checkbox1.onclick = function(){ 
   if(checkbox1.checked != false){ 
   checkbox2.checked =false; }
    } 
   checkbox2.onclick = function(){ 
   if(checkbox2.checked != false){ 
   checkbox1.checked=false;
    }
    } 
   }
```